# Sorting sub array of values with Perl

Tags: perl, sorting

I have the following array pattern:
 **2 letters x numbers 2 letters y numbers 2 letters z numbers** etc..

and I want to sort the numbers between the letters and keep the letters as is.

For example:

```
 a b 3 5 7 4 d c 6 3 2
```

Will become

```
 a b 3 4 5 7 c d 2 3 6
```

How can I implement this in Perl?

What I tried to save the indexes of the letters by

```
my %index=();
my $count =0 ;
foreach (@arr ) {

if($_~=/[a-zA-Z]) {
$index{$_}=$count;
}
$count++

}
```

and then try to replace those sections with splice.

Also I tried the following which seems work:

```
my @a =qw(a b 1 3 5 3  c d 4 5 2);

my (@b,@c) =();
my $count=0;
foreach (@a) {
    if($_=~/[A-Za-z]/){
        push @b,sort @c;
        push @b,$_;
        if($count%2==0) { 
           @c=();
        }
        $count++;
    }
    else {
        push @c,$_;
    }
}
```

I wonder if there a more efficient and Perlish style way to do this?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/) SO is not a write-some-code-for-me site. You'll have to try for yourself and when you're stuck somewhere then state your problem here and you'll get help.

Comment: The above what I have tried

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to loop the array once, keeping the index of the first number encountered in a sequence. When a character is encountered (meaning the number sequence has ended), then sort the number sequence directly in that array slice

```
use strict;
my @arr = ('a','b',3,5,7,4,'d','c',6,3,2);

my $first = -1;
for (my $i = 0; $i < @arr; $i++) {
  if($arr[$i] =~ m/[a-z]/i) {
    next if ($first == -1);
    @arr[$first..($i-1)] = sort {$a<=>$b} @arr[$first..($i-1)];
    $first = -1;
  } elsif ($first == -1) {
    $first = $i;
  } 
}
#one last time after the loop
@arr[$first..(@arr-1)] = sort {$a<=>$b} @arr[$first..(@arr-1)] if ($first != -1);

print join(',',@arr)."\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this more satisfactory?

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @list = ('a', 'b', '3', '5', '7', '4', 'd', 'c', '6', '3', '2');

for (my $i = 0; $i < scalar(@list); $i++)
{
    if ($list[$i] =~ m/[[:alpha:]]/)
    {
        # Assume $list[$i+1] exists and is alphabetic too!
        @list[$i..$i+1] = sort @list[$i..$i+1];
        $i++;
    }
}

print "@list\n";
```

The concept is that when the current entry is alphabetic, the next entry must be too, so sort that slice of the array and increment `$i` so that the second alphabetic character is not processed separately.  The sample output is:

```
a b 3 5 7 4 c d 6 3 2
```

I'm not entirely happy about the repeated slice in the line with the sort, but I'm not sure whether there's a way to avoid that while using `sort`.

Of course, since it is Perl, there's more than one way to do it (TMTOWTDI), so both of these also produce the correct answer.  I'm not sure which is less grotesque.  I'm probably missing some idiomatic way of swapping two variables.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @list = ('a', 'b', '3', '5', '7', '4', 'd', 'c', '6', '3', '2');

for (my $i = 0; $i < scalar(@list); $i++)
{
    if ($list[$i] =~ m/[[:alpha:]]/)
    {
        ($list[$i], $list[$i+1]) = ($list[$i+1], $list[$i]) if ($list[$i] gt $list[$i+1]);
        $i++;
    }
}

print "@list\n";
```

That swapping line is gruesome because of the three references to list elements.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @list = ('a', 'b', '3', '5', '7', '4', 'd', 'c', '6', '3', '2');

for (my $i = 0; $i < scalar(@list); $i++)
{
    if ($list[$i] =~ m/[[:alpha:]]/)
    {
        my($x,$y) = (\$list[$i], \$list[$i+1]);
        ($$x, $$y) = ($$y, $$x) if ($$x gt $$y);
        $i++;
    }
}

print "@list\n";
```

That swapping line is gruesome because it explicitly swaps explicit references.

Comment: If you were going for speed in your second version, I'm pretty sure you made it slower. Would be interesting to compare the two, `($list[$i], $list[$i+1]) = sort ($list[$i], $list[$i+1])` and `my $r = sub { \@_ }->($list[$i], $list[$i+1]); @$r = sort @$r;`. My bet is on the simple sort.